# Can I use silicone as a light adhesive?

Tags: cabinets, mirror

Can I use acrylic w/silicone as a light adhesive  -  wood to glass?  Or is there something better?

**Not** for structural support. (*I'm taking care of that on the sides of the cabinet.  Cabinet sits on a flat vanity surface.*)

Just to mate wood cabinet to the glass mirror behind - to eliminate gap and any possible shifting.

Comment: Epoxy or construction adhesive for glass are the best choice but I can't think of a reason you cannot do it with silicone either. Just don't expect it to have the holding power of the other types.

Comment: If an adhesive utters the word "acrylic" anywhere on the label then I would stay away. Over time it **will** shrink, crack, and fail.

Comment: Make sure to read the labels carefully to make sure the product will work for your application. I believe Loctite Power Grab Ultimate explicitly states it cannot be used on mirrors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can if the label has the word "adhesive" on it. Not all tubes of silicone are adhesives. You have to make sure the mirror is securely fastened to the wall and the cabinet fits flush against it. If possible, you'll want to fasten the cabinet to the vanity to prevent pullout.

Comment: Silicone Glue sound like an acceptable product?

Comment: @Marinaio  Yep, that will do it.

Comment: ge2 kitchen and bath...

Comment: I bought Silicone II Household Glue & Seal (GE280) to try